# I can't update MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't get any errors but I can't update MySQL PHP. I want to change dropdown status from "sedang diproses" dropdown into "Berjaya or Tidak Berjaya". Also I can't change in the database "sedang diproses"  into "Berjaya or Tidak Berjaya"

This is my Code Html

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include ('include/myFunction.php');
    require('include/connect.php');
 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <link href="css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="css/myStyle1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
      <link href="css/myStyle3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <body>
    <div align="right">
      <a href="logout.php" ><img src="img/logout.png" width="63" height="46"  /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header" align="left"><a href="#"><img src="img/gmbar.PNG" width="223" height="126" /></a><!-- end .header --><!-- end .header --></div>
    <div class="content"  style="font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">
    <div class="content"  style="font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"  style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"><a href="senaraipemohon.php">Kembali</a>


    </div>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <?php if($_SESSION['namaadmin'] ==null)
      {
         header('location:index.php');
      }
      else
      {
          ?>
          <form action="prosesstatus.php" method="post">
    <table width="1002" height="87" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
      <tr bgcolor="#00CCFF">
       <td width="30"><strong>Bil</strong></td>
      <td width="298"><strong>Nama</strong></td>
      <td width="176"><strong>Nama Kursus</strong></td>
      <td width="150"><strong>Tarikh Daftar</strong></td>
      <td width="150"><strong>Status</strong></td>
      <td width="168"><strong>Kemaskini Status</strong></td>
       <td width="131"><strong>Pilihan</strong></td>  

      </tr>
      <?php
    $namakursus = ''; 
    if( isset( $_GET['namakursus'])) {
        $namakursus = $_GET['namakursus']; 
    } 

    $sql1 = "Select * from pemohonan INNER JOIN kursus ON pemohonan.idkursus = kursus.idkursus 
      INNER JOIN pemohon ON pemohonan.idPemohon = pemohon.idPemohon WHERE kursus.namakursus = '$namakursus' "; 
    $result1=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql1) or die (mysqli_error());
    $i=1;
      while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
       {
    ?>
      <tr>

        <td><strong><?php echo $i; ?><input name="idkursus" type="hidden" size="50" value="<?php echo $row1['idkursus'];?>"/><input name="idPemohonan" type="hidden" size="50" value="<?php echo $row1['idPemohonan'];?>"/></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row1['nama']; ?></strong><input name="id" type="hidden" size="50" value="<?php echo $row1['idPemohon'];?>"/></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row1['namakursus']; ?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row1['tarikhpemohon']; ?></strong></td>
         <td><strong><?php echo $row1['status']; ?></strong></td>
         <td><select name="status" value="<?php echo $row1['status']; ?>">
              <option value="sila pilih">-Sila Pilih-</option>
              <option value="Berjaya">Berjaya</option>
              <option value="Tidak Berjaya">Tidak Berjaya</option>
              </select></td>

    <td><input name="btnKemaskini" type="submit" value="Kemaskini" /></td>

      </tr>




      <?php

             $i++;

         }
         mysqli_close($dbc);
      }

        ?>
    </table></form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="footer" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
     <?php footertext(); ?>  

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is Image 
[image: example]

This Is My Image DB
[image: database]

This is my Code Php

```
<?php
require ('include/connect.php');

 $idPemohonan = '';
 $idPemohon = ''; 
 $idkursus = ''; 
if (isset($_GET['idPemohon'],$_GET['idkursus'],$_GET['idPemohonan']))
{
$idPemohon = $_GET['idPemohon'];
$idkursus = $_GET['idkursus'];
$idPemohonan = $_GET['idPemohonan'];
}

$tarikhharini=date('y-m-d');
$status=$_POST['status'];

$sql1 = "UPDATE  pemohonan SET  idPemohonan ='$idPemohonan' ,  idPemohon ='$idPemohon' , idkursus ='$idkursus' , tarikhpemohon ='$tarikhharini' , status='$status'
 where idPemohonan = '$idPemohonan' and idPemohon = '$idPemohon'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql1) or die (mysqli_error());
$num_row1 = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);


    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
    echo "alert('Status Pemohonan Telah Dihantar!');\n";
    echo  "window.location='senaraipemohon.php'";
    echo "</script>";


mysqli_close($dbc);



?>
```

Comment: Pleeaase....stop mixing markup + logic + database operations...... _This is my Code Html_ No it is not! It is a mix of all of them

Comment: You need to use mvc architecture to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you haven't sent in
`<form action="prosesstatus.php" method="post">`

Parameters:

`$idPemohon = $_GET['idPemohon'];
 $idkursus = $_GET['idkursus'];
 $idPemohonan =
 $_GET['idPemohonan'];`

If you want use $_GET link should look like:
`prosesstatus.php?idPemohon=value&idkursus=value&idPemohonan=value`

Or you should add these parameters in
Input type hidden and change in php to $_POST

I agree with others than you should use MVC for example some kind of framework  (Laravel, CodeIgniter)
Or separate as much as possible php and html because your code looks unprofessional.
Your MySQL queries are vulnerable to SQL injection and most likely file

`include/connect.php`

is not outside public folder which is not good practice to do.

Comment: Thanks for help..yea maybe i m still beginner

Comment: So sorry if i have make some mistake